# Spring boot and Jersey javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: No available MessageBodyWriter

Tags: spring-boot, jersey

Trying to use Spring Boot and Jersey to call REST Client.
But running into an issue

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: No available MessageBodyWriter for class "class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart" and media type "multipart/mixed"
```

Trying to use Jersey version 2.6
Made sure I have registered MultiPartFeature

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
```

Need to send multipart/mixed as content type in HTTP request.
Any other ideas or help will be appreciated.

Sample Code for MultiPart body

```
MultiPart multiPartEntity = new MultiPart()
    .bodyPart(new BodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("XXXX", payload), 
javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE))
    .bodyPart(new BodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("YYYYY",file), j 
javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
```

Answer (score 0):

> No available MessageBodyWriter for class "class FileDataBodyPart"

You can't use a `FileDataBodyPart` as the entity body. It needs to be a `MultiPart` for which you can *add* a `FileDataBodyPart` to. For example

```
FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("test", new File("test.txt"));
MultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart()
        .bodyPart(filePart);

Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient()
        .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
        .target(url)
        .request()
        .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, "multipart/mixed"));
```

### UPDATE (full tested code)

Not sure what you are doing wrong, but here is the full code that I tested with (using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)). I changed the code below to use `MultiPart` instead of `FormDataMultiPart` per the comment of the OP, but either way, the request was still sent out with a multipart/mixed content type, as that's what I explicitly set with the `Entity`.

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.*;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MutliPartMixedTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {

        @POST
        @Consumes("multipart/mixed")
        @Produces("text/plain")
        public String post(MultiPart multiPart) throws Exception {
            BodyPart part = multiPart.getBodyParts().get(0);
            return part.getEntityAs(String.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig()
                .register(TestResource.class)
                .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
                .register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true))
                .register(new ExceptionMapper<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public Response toResponse(Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                        return Response
                                .serverError()
                                .entity(t.getMessage())
                                .build();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Test
    public void doIt() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            writer.write("Hello World!");
        }
        FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("data", file);
        MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart()
                .bodyPart(filePart);

        try {
            Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient()
                    .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
                    .target("http://localhost:9998/test")
                    .request()
                    .accept("text/plain")
                    .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, "multipart/mixed"));

          assertEquals("Hello World!", response.readEntity(String.class));
        } finally {
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did indeed built it the same way, instead used MultiPart multiPartEntity = new MultiPart(), as content type should be multipart/mixed. I added sample code above.

Comment: Not sure if you're saying that it still isn't working, but I posted a full working test case.

Comment: thanks for the example, this helps.. we ended up with a different solution without jersey.

Comment: by the way.. do you have example with spring boot?

Comment: Despite registering the MultiPartFeature I kept getting the same error. After a tough struggle I decided not to use our project-specific builder,  but instead, brand new one and it started to work.
So my advice is - when in trouble, try fresh simple creation of client. My guess is that registration of MPF somehow got overridden by another component which was registered sooner, within our API.